# ESP32 GND affected by Wifi operation

Tags: adc, esp32

I designed a circuit that use ESP32 to communicate with MCP3204, when I use Wifi to transfer received data, I noticed a lot of spikes, but when I turn off the Wifi, and transfer data through UART, spikes are gone.

So my question is: how to remove those awful spikes?

the upper chart is signal from MCP3204 when nothing is connected

the lower chart is signal from MCP3204 when I plug TL431 output to MCP3204 input

The left side is when Wifi is on, the right is when I turn off Wifi
[image]

Comment: For all we know, it could be your scope lying to you. We know nothing of your schematic, layout and measurement technique. Please add this to your question. If you wanted me to guess, i’d suggest your pcb  layout needs a ground plane and you want the proper capacitors for bypassing the esp32 power.

Comment: some is unavoidable, but adding more caps to the mcp supply will likely help.